# Go to last page with infinite row model type

Tags: pagination, ag-grid

With the changes to how ag-grid fetches server side data (i.e. fetching "blocks" instead of "pages") is there a way to jump to the last page without having to load all of the pages first?

I would like to be able to configure my grid with the following:

```
gridOptions = {
    ...
    rowModelType: 'infinite',
    datasource: 'myDatasource',
    pagination: true,
    ...
}
```

And still have the ability to jump to the last page. This behavior was possible in `v9.0.x` with `rowModelType="pagination"` and was broken with the recent changes to the row model types.

Comment: Did you every find a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pagination API as described here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/

Specifically, you could navigate to the last page with:

`api.paginationGoToLastPage()`

Comment: With the updated `infinite` row model, data is fetched from the server in blocks instead of pages so `api.paginationGoToLastPage()` will only go to the last set of data that has been loaded from the server.

For example, if I have 1000 rows of data and my `pageSize` is 20, my `blockSize` is 100 and i've loaded 2 blocks of data when I have 10 pages available of a total of 50 pages. If I call `paginationGoToLastPage()` it will jump to the last page that has been loaded (i.e. page 10) instead of page 50 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Set scroll height via api e.g. api.setInfiniteRowCount(500)
2. Scroll to new position via api e.g. api.ensureIndexVisible(500)